# SQL - how to select rows based upon values from a different table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've a table called `ranges` which looks like this-

```
create table ranges(low bigint, high bigint, id int);
insert into ranges values (10,20,100);
insert into ranges values (21,30,101);
```

I've another table which looks like this-

```
create table ip(ip bigint);
insert into ip values (12);
```

I want a query which will output the `id` from the `ranges` table if the `ip` from `ip` table is between `low` and `high` of `ranges` table.

For example, for the ip `12`, I want the output to be -

`12,100`

since `12` is between the low `10` and high `20` from the `ranges` table. What is the most efficient way of doing this? the column `ip` doesn't exist in the `ranges` table so I can't do a straightforward join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join a table using range.

```
SELECT
    ip.ip, ranges.id
FROM
    ip
JOIN ranges ON ip.ip BETWEEN ranges.low AND ranges.high
```

Comment: Although it works, on RedShift, it is very slow. I am getting warning- `Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products`

Comment: Right, the join like this is not recommended in large table. Alternatively, if there's a regular interval in `ranges`. You may round up your `ip.ip` to nearest interval base and do a `JOIN`.